# Override some function cakephp (Late Static Bindings )

Tags: php, function, cakephp, overriding, late-static-binding

I use CakePHP 2.9.8 to develop an old application that was written 7 years ago and developed until now.
unfortunately the first developer add some codes in CakePHP's library and for migrating to the 3th version of CakePHP I need to transfer the changing in the application.

one of the changing is in the `App::load` located in `~\lib\Cake\Core\App.php` and as it used `static::_map($file, $className, $plugin);`, I can write a class which extend `App.php` and rewrite the `_map` function.

My questions:

1. Can be override a protected function or property? 
   if no:
2. why in CakePHP they were used (or called) like `static::` for example: `static::_map($file, $className, $plugin);` but the definition is `protected static function _map($file, $name, $plugin = null)`
   if yes:
3. Where in my application should I define class Foo which extend App and for `load` function that I want to remove the developer changes, where should I write Foo::load?.

I put also `App::load` function here:

```
public static function load($className) {
    if (!isset(static::$_classMap[$className])) {
        return false;
    }
    if (strpos($className, '..') !== false) {
        return false;
    }

    $parts = explode('.', static::$_classMap[$className], 2);
    list($plugin, $package) = count($parts) > 1 ? $parts : array(null, current($parts));

    $file = static::_mapped($className, $plugin);
    if ($file) {
        return include $file;
    }
    $paths = static::path($package, $plugin);

    if (empty($plugin)) {
        $appLibs = empty(static::$_packages['Lib']) ? APPLIBS : current(static::$_packages['Lib']);
        $paths[] = $appLibs . $package . DS;
        $paths[] = APP . $package . DS;
        $paths[] = CAKE . $package . DS;
    } else {
        $pluginPath = CakePlugin::path($plugin);
        $paths[] = $pluginPath . 'Lib' . DS . $package . DS;
        $paths[] = $pluginPath . $package . DS;
    }

    $normalizedClassName = str_replace('\\', DS, $className);

    // Start point of custom codes
    // Load Custom Classes that are usually added during customizations
    // This part is for accepting a class like **XControllerCustom** but the name of file is: **XController**
    if($package === 'Model'){
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            $file = $path . DS . $className . '.php';
            $file_custom = $path . 'Custom' . DS . $normalizedClassName . '.php';
            if (file_exists($file_custom) && file_exists($file)) {
                self::_map($file_custom, $className);
                include $file;
                return include $file_custom;
            }
        }
    }
    // End of custom's code     

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $file = $path . $normalizedClassName . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            static::_map($file, $className, $plugin);
            return include $file;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: 1) You can override all protected methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some serious lack of knowledge in OOP in php. Read these links carefully, they'll give you the answers and hopefully a complete understandig of both topics.

1. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Also there are *plenty* of questions and answers related to both on SO. Just search for them if the manual is not sufficient.

---

For number three, there is no fixed place. Just put it in a `Lib` or `Utility` folder inside your app. However, I would choose an autoloader over the built in `App` stuff and just use `uses` to make my classes available. If your app doesn't use composer yet, just add it and use its autoader and namespaces. The only reason 2.x is still not using them is backward compatibility. `App` is a crutch to get namespace like functionality done without actually using them.

Comment: I just didn't know that we can override protected functions in PHP and **not some serious lack of knowledge in OOP in php**. Thanks for the links and explications.

Comment: I consider it serious, as this is mostly the same in probably all OOP capable languages that have a visibility scope keyword. I consider this as a serious lack for that reason. It effectively stops you from understanding and writing certain cases in which you want to use protected or even private. It's not meant as offensive.